# Ubuntu recovery says "fsck from util-linux" and exits

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, data-recovery, fsck

I booted Ubuntu in recovery mode to try and fix a disk error.

However, when I run:

```
fsck
```

I just get:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
```

And nothing else happens.

Any `fsck` command is simply printing 'fsck from util-linux 2.31.1' and exiting, regardless of options and arguments.

This is preventing me from fixing the disk error and being able to recover the system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command I needed was `fsck.ext4`, e.g.

```
fsck.ext4 -F
```

This let me fix the disk issues and recover the system.

Answer (score 2):

When executing filesystem check you need to specify the filesystem itself in to the command line. Its rarely need to flush the filesystem buffers. To check the filesystem use `-f`

```
fsck -f /filesystem
```

To add explicitly type of the filesystem you can use format:

```
fsck -t ext4 -f /filesystem
```

Comment: Any `fsck` command is simply printing 'fsck from util-linux 2.31.1' and exiting, regardless of options and arguments. It seems `fsck.ext4` is the required command in this situation.

Comment: `fsck` usually recognize the filesystem. But its not need to use `fsck.ext4` format, you ac add the type to the `fsck` command itself. See my edited answer

Comment: `fsck -t ext4 -f /filesystem` also just prints `fsck from util-linux 2.31.1` and exits.

Comment: I needed to add /dev/sda1 instead of /filesystem.

Comment: @Virgo, if you do not have records in `/etc/fstab` you should use the device name instead of filesystem mount point